# Firefox inspector - Undoing CSS declarations with CTRL + Z

Tags: css, firefox, devtools, undo

When using **Chrome**, **IE11** or **EDGE** and modifying CSS in the developer tools you can undo the rule/declaration by pressing `CTRL + Z`.

For example: Editing `margin: 16px` to `margin: 14px` I should be able to revert the change with `CTRL + Z` and reapply it with `CTRL + Y`.

I have yet to find a way to do this in Firefox or even finding someone asking for it to be added. This is the only thing stopping me from using Firefox in development.

Is there any way to get this functionality or is it a matter of requesting it from the Mozilla team?

Comment: Hm, you're right. Some implementations have a context menu,but with "Undo" grayed out. Annoying.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this doesn’t have priority for the DevTools team yet.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773510